# Collocations for "compromise"

Tags: collocation

Fairly simple one this time: What’s the best collocation with *compromise* if I want to say that it has been reached and, hopefully, is going to last long?

I’m looking for the most natural, the “first thing that comes to mind” kind of combination.

- stable compromise?
- firm compromise?
- steady compromise?
- strong compromise?
- ____ compromise?

I did a brief Google search but obtained no satisfactory results.

Seems like *stable compromise* is fine, but I'm not sure this is it.

EDIT: Having been reminded of the associations of the word *compromise*, I have hereby modified my question. I'm actually looking for a nice way to express the situation in which two opposing parties have reached an agreement on sth, and the agreement is stable, and it's good, and everybody's happy, and it's white X-mas in Hades. I think that, instead of *compromise*, we could work with *agreement*, *harmony*, *concord* or *consensus*.

Comment: Ah, the **noun** _compromise_; well, what collocates with the **verb** _compromise_?

Comment: _The LTP Dictionary of Selected Collocations_ (p51) lists the following as adjective collocates of the noun _compromise_: _acceptable, definite, early, fair, good, potential, reasonable, (un)satisfactory, shaky, tacit, uneasy_. Verb collocates are are: _agree on/to, aim at, arrive at, come to, effect, negotiate, patch up, reach, reject, seek, work out_.

Comment: I'm going for "unshaky" and "easy" :)

Answer (score 2):

The noun *[compromise](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compromise#Noun)* has multiple senses:

> 1. The settlement of differences by arbitration or by consent reached by mutual concessions.
> 2. A committal to something derogatory or objectionable; a prejudicial concession; a surrender.

The first sense (which presumably applies in this case) is less pejorative than the other, but both senses connote less-than-perfect.  For that reason,  adjectives like *stable, firm, steady*, and *strong* seem unsuitable to me; they introduce a mocking or ironic tone.  Consider, instead, *amicable* or *workable*.  [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amicable+compromise%2Cworkable+compromise&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camicable%20compromise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworkable%20compromise%3B%2Cc0) for *amicable compromise,workable compromise* shows that the former phrase was common before the early 1900s, and the latter since then.

[Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=amicable+compromise%2Cworkable+compromise%2Cacceptable+compromise&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Camicable%20compromise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cworkable%20compromise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacceptable%20compromise%3B%2Cc0) for *amicable compromise,workable compromise,acceptable compromise* shows *acceptable compromise* (as suggested by StoneyB) as slightly more popular, and can be used if it fits with your idea.

Comment: +1 Good. You might plug *acceptable compromise* into your Ngram.

Comment: Maybe it's a cultural/personal thing but I don't see why "compromise" (= making concessions) may be pejorative. Nevertheless, "workable" is close even though I'm not sure a cigar can be expected.

Comment: @jules The problem is that for some people, the very notion of *compromise* involves not getting some things you want **and** getting some things you don’t want, both of which are something like anti-goals. This can overshadow the goal-condition of reaching some sort of agreement. It may be mutual concession, and in fact must be, but it is concession nonetheless, and this can rankle. Furthermore, there **is** a sense of *(to) compromise* that is seen as negative, as in *compromising oneself*; also the OED cites *The Emperor··disowned his compromised minister in London.*, which is negative.

Comment: Seaching [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) for collocating adjectives that precede the noun 
*compromise*, the first seven such collocations are *possible, acceptable, final, new, bipartisan, successful,* and *perfect*.

Comment: @tchrist Well, maybe I should go look for another word that's less problematic for the speakers of EN? "Agreement"? "Harmony"? "Concord"? "Consensus"?

Comment: @jules Perhaps so; to me at least *agreement* or *consensus* carries less baggage than does *compromise*, and does not risk compromising the sense.

Comment: Fine, so we've reached an agreement/a consensus, and I hope it will be "..........."?

Comment: @jules, consider *long-lasting* agreement, *enduring* or *durable* consensus, etc

Comment: "durable consensus" - that really nice.